# Extract first six occurrences of a variable by ID

Tags: r

I have a dataset where individuals all enrolled at different time periods. I am hoping to look at changes in the number of activities an individual participates in over the first six months of that persons study period. How can I realign the dataset to have everyone's first occurrence be "time 1" and so on? I feel like it should be a simple solution and I could go through and manually do it but I have a lot of observations, so I would rather not.

Here is an example of the data I have:

| ID | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | . | 34 | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 | 10 | . | 10 | 16 |
| 2 | 22 | 34 | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 | . | . | . | . |
| 3 | . | . | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 | 45 | 80 | 15 | 12 |

I am hoping to make the dataset look like this:

| ID | Time 1 | Time 2 | Time 3 | Time 4 | Time 5 | Time 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 | 10 |
| 2 | 22 | 34 | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 |
| 3 | 36 | 72 | 89 | 23 | 45 | 80 |

Comment: What is the format of your data set? It looks like the columns are numeric, but it is not possible to have empty cells in a numeric column. Could you perhaps [edit] your question to include a sample of your real data using `dput(df)`, where `df` is the name of your actual data set? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(time = list(na.omit(c_across(any_of(month.name)))[1:6]),
         .by = ID, .keep = "unused") |>
  unnest_wider(time, names_sep = "")

# OR 

df |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, values_drop_na = T) |>
  mutate(name = row_number(), .by = ID) |>
  filter(name <= 6) |>
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "time", id_cols = ID)
```

Here is a row-wise base R solution:

```r
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df, 1, \(x) na.omit(x[-1])[1:6]))) |> 
  setNames(c(colnames(df[1]), paste0("time", 1:6)))
```

**Output**

```
     ID time1 time2 time3 time4 time5 time6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    34    36    72    89    23    10
2     2    22    34    36    72    89    23
3     3    36    72    89    23    45    80
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, May = c(NA, 22L, NA), June = c(34L, 
34L, NA), July = c(36L, 36L, 36L), August = c(72L, 72L, 72L), 
    September = c(89L, 89L, 89L), October = c(23L, 23L, 23L), 
    November = c(10L, NA, 45L), December = c(NA, NA, 80L), January = c(10L, 
    NA, 15L), February = c(16L, NA, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First preprocess your data (see below section *Data*).

For explicitly using *n* columns disregarding `NA`, try this:

```
n <- 7
cbind(dat['ID'], time=t(apply(as.matrix(dat[-1]), 1, \(x)
                              `length<-`(head(na.omit(x)), n))))
#   ID time.1 time.2 time.3 time.4 time.5 time.6 time.7
# 1  1     34     36     72     89     23     10     NA
# 2  2     22     34     36     72     89     23     NA
# 3  3     36     72     89     23     45     80     NA
```

I deliberately used n=7 to illustrate the difference to the next solution, which yields `max`imum available columns.

```
cbind(dat['ID'], time=t(apply(as.matrix(dat[-1]), 1, \(x)
                              head(na.omit(x), min(rowSums(!is.na(dat[-1])))))))
#   ID time.1 time.2 time.3 time.4 time.5 time.6
# 1  1     34     36     72     89     23     10
# 2  2     22     34     36     72     89     23
# 3  3     36     72     89     23     45     80
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <-read.table(header=TRUE, text='
ID  May June    July    August  September   October November    December    January February
1   .   34  36  72  89  23  10  .   10  16
2   22  34  36  72  89  23  .   .   .   .
3   .   .   36  72  89  23  45  80  15  12')

dat[dat == '.'] <- NA  ## pts to NA
dat[-1] <- type.convert(dat[-1], as.is=TRUE)  ## all except ID to numeric
```